# Future<bool> function returns null value flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

Before posting I took at look at previous questions (because there are many) but I didn't find something that suited my needs.

I have a function that checks if a document exists or not on Firestore, then if the document exists the function must return false, otherwise if not exists, true.

The problem is that the return of the function is always null and also compiler told me that the function doesn't have a return statement but I don't understand why.

This is the code, the important function is `checkMissingId` the other one just checks if the string `id` has a valid format or not.

Code :

```
bool checkStr(String id, String letter, String str) {
  if (id.length < 1) {
    print("Id is too short");
    return false;
  } else {
    if ('a'.codeUnitAt(0) > letter.codeUnitAt(0) ||
        'z'.codeUnitAt(0) < letter.codeUnitAt(0)) {
      print("User name begins with bad word!");
      return false;
    }
    print("ids/tabs/" + letter);
    return true;
  }
}

Future<bool> checkMissingId(String id, context) async {
  String str = id.toLowerCase();
  String letter = str[0];
  if (checkStr(id, letter, str) == false)
    return false; //checks some rules on strings
  else {
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("ids/tabs/" + letter).doc(str).get()
          .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) { //Maybe here!(??)
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          print("Document exists!");
          return false;
        } else {
          print('Document does not exist on the database');
          return true;
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      await showErrDialog(context, e.code);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You await the operaion in your `try` block, but you never return a value. By the way, why do you mix `await` and `then` syntaxes? Seems counterintuitive.

Comment: to get the `Future<bool>` value you should use it like this: `Future.value(false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using both `await` and `.then()` for getting data from Firestore. Replace your function with this to get desired result:

```dart
Future<bool> checkMissingId(String id, context) async {
  String str = id.toLowerCase();
  String letter = str[0];
  if (checkStr(id, letter, str) == false) return false; //checks some rules on strings
  else {
    try {
      DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("ids/tabs/" + letter).doc(str).get();
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print("Document exists!");
        return false;
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist on the database');
        return true;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      await showErrDialog(context, e.code);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The other guy was faster but I appreciate it! By the way you're commenting a lots of my post so thank you!

Comment: No problem. Yes, I just realised that it was your post yesterday too

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```dart
Future<bool> checkMissingId(String id, context) async {
  String str = id.toLowerCase();
  String letter = str[0];
  if (checkStr(id, letter, str) == false)
    return false; //checks some rules on strings
  else {
    try {
      var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("ids/tabs/" + letter).doc(str).get()
        if (data.exists) {
          print("Document exists!");
          return false;
        } else {
          print('Document does not exist on the database');
          return true;
        }
    } catch (e) {
      await showErrDialog(context, e.code);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem was that in the `.then(...)` function, it takes a function as input. So, you wouldn't be able to return anything. Because it doesn't return data to your function.

Comment: That's wrong. `.then()` *can* return a `Future`, and it *does* return a `Future<bool>` in the OP's code. He, however, does not return anything in the `try` block, and mixes the two syntaxes, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You're right I mixed because I had some troubles while coding and I didn't clear the code.

Comment: Yes, but my code should help correct that. So, that shoudn't be a problem.

Comment: yes it solved, I put "then" random there, I was stupid :S